# Detect Number of Times pdflatex was run

Tags: pdftex, auxiliary-files

I would like to include information in the pdf to indicate of how many times `pdflatex` was run. This seems pretty trivial, but I can't seem to get this to work -- must be someting obvious.

The output works fine the first time (since the `.aux` file does not exist). But, after that it is stuck at:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}\pagecolor{white}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\CurrentRunNumber}{0}%
\IfFileExists{\jobname.aux}{%
    % Set via the .aux file
}{%
    \def\CurrentRunNumber{1}%
}%
\AtEndDocument{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\@NewRunNumber}{\CurrentRunNumber+1}%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
      \noexpand\def\noexpand\CurrentRunNumber{\@NewRunNumber}%
    }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Run Count: \CurrentRunNumber
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\gdef`, perhaps?

Comment: @egreg: Hmmm.. You aren't sure. :-). Thanks, that works great

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.aux` file is read inside a group. Use `\gdef`. No need for `pgfmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\providecommand{\CurrentRunNumber}{1}
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \gdef\noexpand\CurrentRunNumber{\the\numexpr\CurrentRunNumber+1}
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Run Count: \CurrentRunNumber
\end{document}
```

After two runs, for instance, the `.aux` file will be

```
\relax
\gdef \CurrentRunNumber {2}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

Comment: Is `\CurrentRunNumber` becoming `\the\numexpr \the\numexpr ... +1 +1`? Or the `\the` will be expanded by the `\write`? I am asking because the former sounds funny.

Comment: @Symbol1 `\write` stores the token list and expands it at the moment the write operation is performed. That's why one needs `\gdef\noexpand\CurrentRunNumber` so `\gdef\CurrentRunNumber` is written out; but `\the` is expanded. I'll add the contents after two runs. Note that `\noexpand` is not needed in front of `\gdef`, because this is an unexpandable token.

Comment: Nice! But don't try this with `latexmk` ... (spoiler: I know it will stop after a while, but...)

Comment: BTW, auto-commenting my comment: solvable by adding `$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'aux'}='.*CurrentRunNumber.*';` to your `latexmkrc`. I think.